# How can I lock a single thread in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to "lock" a resource on a single thread. I have tried every locking mechanism I can think of but I cannot make this work.

In the example below when the Timer fires I do not want the code in DoSomething to execute until ShowDialog returns. I expected the lock statement to only allow one instance of Form2 to return but this is actually all running on one thread so it does not stop the thread from re-entering that block of code.

Here is some sample code, this isn't the exact scenario I am facing but it illustrates the problem. In my actual code I am receiving events from an attached device so there is no timer.

To reproduce create a Windows Forms app and add Form1 and Form2. Copy this code into Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer _timer = new Timer();
    private static object _lock = new object();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _timer.Tick += delegate { DoSomething(); };
        _timer.Interval = 5000;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect it to do? It isn't really clear from your question.

Comment: How do you know it isn't working?

Comment: What resource are you trying to lock?

Comment: I updated the question with more details in paragraph 2. Sorry if that isn't clear. I am trying to only have one instance of Form2 visible at 1 time.

Comment: @Shaun - What does that have to do with threading?

Comment: @Ritch I removed the threading tag. My goal is simply to prevent re-entrancy of a method on a single thread. Generally when dealing with locks I am trying to prevent multiple threads from accessing a resource not the same thread.

Answer (score 4):

A flag should do the trick, if you use `ThreadStaticAttribute`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer _timer = new Timer();
    [ThreadStatic]
    bool inEvent = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _timer.Tick += delegate { DoSomething(); };
        _timer.Interval = 5000;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        // if you want to stay here and wait instead of exiting, you could do:
        // while (inEvent);
        if (!inEvent)
        {
            inEvent = true;
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.ShowDialog();
            inEvent = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the `ThreadStatic` attribute should be applied to *static* fields: `[ThreadStatic] static bool inEvent;`

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you create one instance of the form, store it in a class variable, then use check its Visible property?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible.aspx

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer _timer = new Timer();
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _timer.Tick += delegate { DoSomething(); };
        _timer.Interval = 5000;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        if(!form2.Visible)
        {
           form2.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As long as threading isn't an issue, something like this seems like the obvious route.

Comment: Why hold onto the entire form and potentially expose everything about it to a larger scope when all you need is a boolean variable indicating that you're currently handling an event?  Also note that this is re-using the same form, which it may not be intended for, and it also prevents it from ever being garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

Shaun, it sounds like the others are not addressing you actual problem.  Looks like you are presenting a bigger problem in a simple solution.  Anyway, lock won't end up working on the same thread.  It is meant for blocking other threads.  If a lock is encountered on the same thread, it just increments a ref count or something and allows entry only blocking other threads until the ref count goes to zero.

So initially I thought that a Mutex, Semaphore, SpinWait, SpinUntil would help but while they would end up blocking meeting your need to prevent entry, however, your application would then be locked up and waiting because you are on the UI thread so you won't even be able to close the Form2 (or whatever it is you are handling).

To be honest I don't know the proper way to solve the problem.  I would think there would be a pattern or built in functionality to do this but I am unaware of it.  However, if you can create another thread you that may solve your problem as the code below shows.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer _timer = new Timer();
    private readonly static object _lock = new object();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _timer.Tick += delegate { OnTimerTick(); };
        _timer.Interval = 5000;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void OnTimerTick()
    {
        new System.Threading.Thread (DoSomething).Start();
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before Lock");

        lock(_lock)
        {
            // Do stuff...

            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.ShowDialog();

        }

        Console.WriteLine("After Lock");
    }
}
```

Good luck.  If this helped don't forget to vote this answer up.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Why complicate the code with additional threads when all you need is a boolean variable, as shown in the answer posed 5 hours before yours...